# Unable to deploy Log4j 1.x migration to Log4j2x webapp into Oracle weblogic 12.2.1.3 server

Tags: spring-mvc, deployment, log4j, log4j2, weblogic12c

I am seeing the deployment failure for the Log4j 1.x migration to Log4j2x webapp in Oracle weblogic 12.2.1.3. The same webapp is deployed fine in Embedded Jetty server in Eclipse.
Below mentioned jars are used

```
1) javax.servlet-api - 3.0.1
2) log4j-over-slf4j - 1.7.26
3) log4j-slf4j-impl - 2.11.2
4) jcl-over-slf4j - 1.7.26
5) jul-to-slf4j - 1.7.26
6) log4j-web -2.11.2
7) slf4j-api - 1.7.26
```

### Web.xml

```
<!-- Log4j2 initialization in a web environment. -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>log4jConfiguration</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:log4j2.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

### Log4j2.xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<Configuration status = "debug">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="log-path">servers/AdminServer/logs/</Property>
    </Properties>

    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile name="file" fileName="${log-path}/yyy-app.log"
            filePattern="${log-path}/yyy-app.log.%i.gz">
            <PatternLayout pattern = "%d{DEFAULT} %-5p [%c{1}] [%X{uuid}|%X{activityId}]: %m%n" />
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB" />
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="20" />
        </RollingFile>

        <RollingFile name="soap_messages"
            fileName="${log-path}/yyy-soap.log"
            filePattern="${log-path}/yyy-soap.log.%i.gz">
            <PatternLayout
                pattern="%d{DEFAULT} %-5p [%c{1}] [%X{uuid}|%X{activityId}]: %m%n" />
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="50 MB" />
            </Policies> 
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="5" />
            <LevelRangeFilter maxLevel="WARN" onMatch="ACCEPT"
                onMismatch="DENY" />
        </RollingFile>

        <RollingFile name="xxx_security"
            fileName="${log-path}/yyy-security.log"
            filePattern="${log-path}/yyy-security.log.%i.gz">
            <PatternLayout
                pattern="%d{DEFAULT} %-5p [%c{1}] [%X{uuid}|%X{activityId}]: %m%n" />
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="50 MB" />
            </Policies> 
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="5" />
            <LevelRangeFilter maxLevel="WARN" onMatch="ACCEPT"
                onMismatch="DENY" />
        </RollingFile>

    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="com.xxx.yyy.zzz" level="info" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="file" />
        </Logger>

        <Logger
            name="com.xxx.yyy.zzz.webservice.impl.ServiceImpl"
            level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="file" />
        </Logger>

        <Logger
            name="com.xxx.yyy.architecture.cxf.log.interceptor.LoggingInterceptor"
            level="info" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="soap_messages" />
        </Logger>


        <Logger name="org.springframework.security" level="warn"
            additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="xxx_security" />
        </Logger>

        <Root level="error">
            <AppenderRef ref="file" />
        </Root>

    </Loggers>

</Configuration>
```

Seeing below failure in the weblogic console once imported .war file and clicked on next in console.

```
**Error org.springframework.ldap.core.CollectingAuthenticationErrorCallback**
 <The list of resource packages: org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider;org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.validation;com.xxx.yyy.rest.eappcase.service;com.xxx.yyy.rest.eapp.service;com.xxx.yyy.rest.eappworker.service;com.xxx.yyy.rest.eappoffice.service> 
<Dec 16, 2019 6:15:56,646 AM EST> <Error> <J2EE> <BEA-160228> <AppMerge failed to merge your application. If you are running AppMerge on the command-line, merge again with the -verbose option for more details. See the error message(s) below.> 
weblogic.utils.compiler.ToolFailureException: org.springframework.ldap.core.CollectingAuthenticationErrorCallback
    at weblogic.application.compiler.FlowDriver.handleStateChangeException(FlowDriver.java:55)
    at weblogic.application.compiler.FlowDriver.nextState(FlowDriver.java:38)
    at weblogic.application.compiler.AppMerge.runBody(AppMerge.java:168)
    at weblogic.utils.compiler.Tool.run(Tool.java:159)
    at weblogic.utils.compiler.Tool.run(Tool.java:116)
    at weblogic.application.compiler.AppMerge.merge(AppMerge.java:198)
    at weblogic.deploy.api.internal.utils.AppMerger.merge(AppMerger.java:94)
    at weblogic.deploy.api.internal.utils.AppMerger.getMergedApp(AppMerger.java:58)
    at weblogic.deploy.api.model.internal.WebLogicDeployableObjectFactoryImpl.createDeployableObject(WebLogicDeployableObjectFactoryImpl.java:186)
    at weblogic.deploy.api.model.internal.WebLogicDeployableObjectFactoryImpl.createLazyDeployableObject(WebLogicDeployableObjectFactoryImpl.java:160)
    at weblogic.deploy.api.tools.SessionHelper.inspect(SessionHelper.java:781)
```

Any help/suggestion would be a great help.

Comment: Application servers (JBoss, WebLogic etc.) typically provide  implementations of various libraries. You may need to change the server settings to give preference to those bundled with your application. See, for example: http://www.freshjavabeans.com/fjb/2015/05/14/override-jars-in-weblogic-libraries-and-use-those-in-your-ear-war/ and https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e21049/weblogic_xml.htm#WBAPP663

Comment: Thanks Alan.I tried your suggestion and still see the issue persists.
Deployment is failing in weblogic server.
Unable to access the selected application.
org.springframework.ldap.core.CollectingAuthenticationErrorCallback
org.springframework.ldap.core.CollectingAuthenticationErrorCallback
Error org.springframework.ldap.core.CollectingAuthenticationErrorCallback